# How can I turn off music automatically starting after phone call in iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones, music.app

I use an iPhone 11 with a Sennheiser noise cancelling PXC 550-II Bluetooth headset.

Every time I end a phone call, the iPhone starts playing a seemingly random song from my music library. I understand the benefit from pausing music during a phone call, but when music was turned off before the call, I expect it to stay that way after the call.

I looked, and it seems MacOS has similar issues, but there is no mention (or solution) for the iPhone.

So is it

1. Me, because I overlooked a setting in iPhone
2. some bug in IOS, or
3. the Sennheiser headset?

I sort of hope for 1) because that would be a quick fix instead of having to report bugs to the vendors.

Comment: A recommendation I'd test with is to try another Bluetooth headset and see if the same results apply on your iPhone or Mac. See if someone can at least let you borrow theirs or even better attempt to pair them and then make a call with them and see if music plays after the end of the call. If the issue persists its likely an Apple issue. If not then you'll probably need to report this behavior to the Sennheiser support team. They should be able to fix it via an update or possibly shipping you a replacement headset (you may need to still be within a warranty period).

Comment: @MelvinJefferson: Good Advice. I will try that and report back. I take it isn't a common problem, but you think it's linked to my headset phone combination?

Comment: To clarify - you are listening to music, then pause the playback, make a phone call, end the phone call, and the music restarts automatically? Is that the sequence? OR does the music start playing after you end a phonecall _if you have not been already listening to music._?

Comment: @IconDaemon: Yes. In general that's the sequence. Music is stopped. e.g. since yesterday. Then I connect my headset, make a phone call or get called. End call.  Music starts. Not always reproducable though. just testing this, I had to send the phone to standby and reactivate (on/off button right) for the music to start.

Comment: And now I'm trying for 15 minutes and cannot reproduce it at all - driving me crazy.

Comment: Try it like this exmplaining: [10 Best Fixes to Solve the Problem: iPhone Plays Music by Itself](https://tunesgo.wondershare.com/iphone-problems/iphone-plays-music-by-itself.html)

Comment: Yes, @TobiM I think it's linked to your headset period, mostly because of the Mac reproducing the problem. But testing another headset and getting different results can rule that out.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it is a (typically) poor implementation in the bluetooth headset.

I have the same issue with two different cars that are connected to the iPhone via bluetooth. I guess the developer writing the code for the device couldn't imagine that anyone wasn't listening to music, so he hardcoded to start the music after the call ends.

I could not find a solution in many years, and have now disconnected my iPhone from the car for that reason. Obviously not useful for you, as a bluetooth headset that is not connected is useless (whereas the car still drives).

Comment: Not very encuraging, but helpful information - thanks.